# Java anonymous inner class calling enclosing type super types method

Tags: java, anonymous-inner-class, default-method

I give you an example to set some context here, so I have two interfaces each inheriting the same parent interface and defining their own implementation of the parent interface's abstract method.

```
interface A
{
    Set a();
}

interface B extends A
{
    @Override
    default Set a()
    {
        return null;
    }
}

interface C extends A
{
    @Override
    default Set a()
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

In an interface called `D`, The implementation creates an anonymous inner class which then needs to call the super types (`B` and `C`) `a()` implementation.

```
interface D extends B, C
{
    @Override
    default Set a()
    {
        return new HashSet()
        {
            {
                final int totalSize = D.this.B.super.a().size() + D.this.C.super.a().size();
            }
        };
    }
}
```

The problem is that the expressions `D.this.B.super.a()` and `D.this.C.super.a()` do not get compiled successfully, so what is up ?

Thank you by the way for your efforts.

Comment: "do not get compiled successfully" What is the error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Java allows you to access specific interface implementations with the syntax:

```
InterfaceName.super.method()
```

However, inside the anonymous class to get the enclosing instance with `D.this`.  It is not allowed to combine these syntaxes to first get the enclosing instance, then its super-interface implementations.

The solution here is to move the declaration of `totalSize` outside of the anonymous class so you can access the super-interface implementations.  The anonymous class will still be able to refer to the local variable `totalSize` because it's `final`.  (It would still be able to access it if it were effectively final -- not `final` but never reassigned.)

```
final int totalSize = B.super.a().size() + C.super.a().size();
return new HashSet()
{
     // Anonymous class implementation here.
     // You can refer to totalSize.
};
```

You may have omitted the generics for brevity, but in case you didn't, you will want to include type parameters for `Set` and `HashSet`.

Comment: make sure that neither of `B.super.a()` and `C.super.a()` returns `null`

Comment: and don't use raw types

Comment: @AndrewTobilko chill dude, i used null as a return expression and raw types just for setting context purposes.

Comment: Nevertheless the points about checking for `null` and not using raw types are useful for other people who will view this post.

Comment: @rgettman thank you for the response and feel free to edit my question so that it is helpful and easily readable to other viewers :)